# What is the difference between Ethereum and Eris?

Tags: eris-industries

When I first searched for Turing complete blockchains towards the end of 2015 Google returned both **Eris** and **Ethereum** at the top. My initial impression was that they are quite distinct. More recently though I read that Eris is a spinoff. What exactly is their relationship, if any, and how do they compare?

Answer (score 12):

*Disclosure I'm the CEO of Eris Industries*

`eris` is a blockchain application platform which normalizes many development activities when building a blockchain backed application. It is agnostic as to what the underlying blockchain technology; although admittedly when using some blockchain clients `eris` provides nominal value beyond configuring, starting and stopping (*e.g.*, it doesn't currently allow you to, say, put an EVM over Zcash).

With respect to smart contract enabled chain clients `eris` provides a range of tooling beyond simply configuring, starting and stopping chain clients.

We do make a blockchain client as well, called `eris:db`. eris:db was the first to market with a permissionable blockchain design. It is a tendermint consensus engine connected to an application manager (which contains a permission layer) connected to a built to specification EVM. `eris` exposes a lot more tooling around eris:db (via the `eris chains` namespace) as permissionable chain clients have more complexity to properly work with.

We think that right now the EVM is the market leading smart contract interpreter and it is true that we have a range of tooling around the EVM.

I've answered more of the differences between [geth and eris:db here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/949/how-does-the-microsoft-azure-ethereum-blockchain-as-a-service-differ-from-the-pl/965#965).

Comment: Are there any examples of `eris:db` (with the terdermint consensus engine) running in production?

Comment: Yes; although unfortunately the ones we know of are currently NDA'ed and the rest are in stealth.

Comment: Not having a concrete public example is a barrier to entry for outsider developers/companies. For those not within the inner circles, NDAware and stealthware is basically vaporware.

Comment: @Randomblue second that ^

Answer (score 9):

Eris is a services company that targets banks to deploy private blockchains. They employ Ethereum and have forked it but also seem to include some other technology and wrappers that provide additional tools for private companies to leverage blockchains. You can see a lot of [Eris' git-hub projects](https://github.com/eris-ltd) are related to ethereum.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wd4wDnnG5uc) is Preston Byrne (Eris Co-founder, COO) talking about their view on blockchain and how private companies can use it.

[This slideshare](http://slideshare.net/BlockstarsIO/innopay-eris-and-ethereum) might also help distinguish them

Comment: you can edit your answer to include additional information.