# Is it possible to use web3.js API methods to interact with Eris chains

Tags: web3js, eris-industries

Is it possible to use the Web3.js API methods to interact with Eris blockchain? If yes, what should I pass in as the argument for setting the web3 provider?

Answer (score 1):

Since Eris is a permissioned blockchain, you will have to make the permission-logic inside your api layer to make it work. Eris is technically a fork of Ethereum with improvements. [*source*](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1015/259). Web3 should work out of the box, but i am not sure whether they internally disabled it or not.

**But there is eris-db.js**

> Javascript library that calls an erisdb server over rpc. It is a controllable (permissionable), smart contract-enabled, proof-of-stake based blockchain design. eris:db can be configured to work with a wide variety of individual blockchain networks. As such, it was, and continues to be, the first blockchain client designed from the ground up to be a multi-network blockchain client.

Take a look at the [examples](https://github.com/eris-ltd/eris-db.js/tree/master/templates/example_database)

Comment: Yes, I know about eris-db.js but I was just wondering if it would be possible to use plain web3 methods to interact with eris chains. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Eris is a different chin, I dont know whether it is possible to do it using web3.