# I don't see any environment when deployed ethereum on Azure

Tags: solidity, private-blockchain, microsoft-azure

Just started with ethereum block chain and done with the theory part.

As part of my work I need to do a sample POC of SmartContract + Private Blockchain on Azure.

I created Ubuntu VM from "Ethereum Consortium Blockchain" hoping all the required environment will be preconfigured in the VM. I also created a account on ether.camp.

But when I opened the machine I see it empty, I cant find any environment related to ethereum as mentioned in this post.

[How does the Microsoft Azure Ethereum Blockchain as a Service differ from the platform offered by Eris Industries?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/949/how-does-the-microsoft-azure-ethereum-blockchain-as-a-service-differ-from-the-pl)

The ether.camp account is having a single project created with a sample Contracts.

please help me on the following

> Creating a private block chain and setting up an environment.
>
> Creating a new project in ether.camp.
>
> Deploying or connecting these contracts to the private blockchain.

Any links which explain in detail will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Mahesh Gupta P

Answer (score 1):

I was able to start a private blockchain on Azure by using the "Ethereum Consortium Leader". Once the resource is deployed you can use the click on the "Resources " tile that now displays.

A new screen will display on the left click "Deployments". Then click on the resource which is the blockchain something like . There will be a list including the load balancer, vm, and templates.

This is get to the resources on your private blockchain. These are need for truffle migrations.

Use the "SSH-TO-FIRST-TX-NODE" link in a shell to create an ssh session and unlock the default account created:

```
geth attach
personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase)
<passphrase used to create the Azure blockchain>
```

This needs to produce "true". That means the account is unlocked and you can "migrate" to it.

My example truffle.js file:

```
module.exports = {
// See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
// to customize your Truffle configuration!
networks: {
    rpc: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 8545,
        network_id: "*"
    },
    "live": {
        host: "<Azure ETHEREUM-RPC-ENDPOINT without the http:// and port number>",
        port: 8545,
        network_id: "1",
        gas: 4612388 // default: 4712388
    }
}
```

};

```
truffle compile
truffle migrate --network live
```

This should get you started.